# How to make ExampleMatcher to match just one property?

Tags: java, spring-data, matcher, query-by-example

How to implement ExampleMatcher, to match just one property randomly from my class and ignore the other properties?

Assume my class like this :

```
Public Class Teacher() {
    String id;
    String name;
    String address;
    String phone;
    int area;
    ..other properties is here...
}
```

If I want to match by the name:

```
Teacher TeacherExample = new Teacher("Peter");

ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAny()
.withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
.withIgnoreCase()
.withIgnorePaths("id", "address", "phone","area",...);   //no name
```

and if I want to match by the address:

```
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAny()
.withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
.withIgnoreCase()
.withIgnorePaths("id", "name", "phone","area",...); //no address
```

so I need to repeat the `withIgnorePaths(..)` How to avoid that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Teacher t = new Teacher("Peter");
Example<Teacher> te = Example.of(t,
    ExampleMatcher.matching()
        .withStringMatcher(StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
        .withIgnoreCase());
```

With `ExampleMatcher.matching()` or `ExampleMatcher.matchingAll()` comparison is done against all non-null fields in your example teacher `t` so just name (assumed from "Peter").

**NOTE**: with primitive values you just need to add them to `withIgnorePaths(..)` or change them to boxed types like `int -> Integer`, there are no other easy workarounds.

If you need to search only by `int area` set no name but are
 in your example `t`

```
t.setArea(55);
```

or if you had `Date created`, searching by created:

```
t.setCreated(someDate);
```

you can even set them all to narrow the search by applying them all.

From [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/ExampleMatcher.html#matching--)

> static ExampleMatcher matching()
>   ( & static ExampleMatcher matchingAll() )
>
> Create a new ExampleMatcher including all non-null properties by default matching all predicates derived from the example.

Comment: I think this is not working for me, since i have other properties with numeric type. (int area).  When i create new teacher, that area will be fill  with 0 by java default.(can't be null) since it's integer.

Comment: And, how if I also have properties with datetime type ??

Comment: @JiguJigu updated the answer. Update also your question with new details instead of putting them as a comment it helps others to answer.

Comment: i change the property type to Interger. Thank You